# User not created -JSON Exception: End of input at character 0 of

Tags: java, android, json

I am trying to add user details from my application to the php backend. The app is in android studio. But for some reason i am not able to add the user in the database and when i run log in android studio i see these error poping up. When running the app on emulator or actual device it says user not created.

Here is my error log:

```
2019-12-17 13:03:49.521 18785-18785 E/EnhancedIntentService: binding to the service failed

2019-12-17 13:04:04.203 18785-18891 E/Buffer Error: Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException

2019-12-17 13:04:04.204 18785-18891 E/JSON Parser: Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    private final JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    // url to get all products list
    private static final String url = config.mainurl + "create_user.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_FIRSTNAME = "firstname";
    private static final String TAG_LASTNAME = "lastname";
    private static final String TAG_USERNAME = "username";
    private static final String TAG_GUSERNAME = "gusername";
    private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String TAG_MOBILE = "mobile";
    private static final String TAG_PASSWORD = "password";
    private static final String TAG_OTHER = "other";
    private static final String TAG_PROMOCODE = "promocode";

    //Textbox
    private EditText firstname;
    private EditText lastname;
    private EditText username;
    private EditText gusername;
    private EditText email;
    private EditText mobile;
    private EditText password;
    private EditText promocode;
    private Button signup;
    private Button signin;

    private int success;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        firstname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.firstname);
        lastname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lastname);
        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        gusername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.gusername);
        email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        mobile = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mobileNumber);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        promocode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.promocode);

        signup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.registerBtn);
        signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(checkdetails()) {
                    // Loading offers in Background Thread
                    new OneLoadAllProducts().execute();
                }
            }
        });

        signin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginFromRegister);
        signin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
    }

    private boolean checkdetails() {

        //special character checking


        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^a-z0-9]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher m = p.matcher("I am a string"+username.getText().toString());
        boolean b = m.find();

        if (b)
            System.out.println("Rajan_There is a special character in my string");

        if (email.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Enter Value for Email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            email.requestFocus();
            return false;
        } else if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email.getText().toString().trim()).matches()) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Enter valid Value for Email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            email.requestFocus();
            return false;
        } else if (password.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Enter Value for Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            password.requestFocus();
            return false;
        } else if (firstname.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Enter Value for FirstName", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            firstname.requestFocus();
            return false;
        } else if (lastname.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Enter Value for LastName", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            lastname.requestFocus();
            return false;
        } else if (username.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Enter Value for Username", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            username.requestFocus();
            return false;
        } else if (p.matcher(username.getText().toString()).find()) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Enter Username without any special characters", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            username.requestFocus();
            return false;
        } else if (gusername.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Enter Value for G Username", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            pubgusername.requestFocus();
            return false;
        } else if (mobile.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Enter Value for Mobile", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mobile.requestFocus();
            return false;
        } else if (!Patterns.PHONE.matcher(mobile.getText().toString().trim()).matches()) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Enter Valid Value for MobileNumber", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mobile.requestFocus();
            return false;
        }


        return true;
    }

    class OneLoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting All products from url
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put(TAG_FIRSTNAME, firstname.getText().toString().trim());
            params.put(TAG_LASTNAME, lastname.getText().toString().trim());
            params.put(TAG_USERNAME, username.getText().toString().trim());
            params.put(TAG_GUSERNAME, gusername.getText().toString().trim());
            params.put(TAG_EMAIL, email.getText().toString().trim());
            params.put(TAG_MOBILE, mobile.getText().toString().trim());
            params.put(TAG_PASSWORD, password.getText().toString().trim());
            params.put(TAG_OTHER, "");
            params.put(TAG_PROMOCODE, promocode.getText().toString().trim());

            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url, "POST", params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();

            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /*
                      Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     */
                    if (success == 1) {
                        // offers found
                        // Getting Array of offers

                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Registration done Succsessfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    } else if(success == 2){
                        // no offers found
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Email/mobile/username is already exist. change it and try again!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"User not created",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }

                }
            });

        }

    }
}
```

JSONparser.java

```
import android.util.Log;

import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;

public class JSONParser {

    private static InputStream is = null;
    private static JSONObject jObj = null;
    private static String json = "";

    private Integer status = 0;

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
                                      Map<String, String> params) {

        //for builing a parameter
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        boolean first = true;

        int i = 0;
        for (String key : params.keySet()) {
            try {
                if (i != 0){
                    result.append("&");
                }
                result.append(key).append("=")
                        .append(URLEncoder.encode(params.get(key), "UTF-8"));

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            i++;
        }

        System.out.println("string"+result.toString());


        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(Objects.equals(method, "POST")){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                URL urlr = new URL(url);
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlr.openConnection();

                conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
                /* for Get request */
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

                conn.setDoInput(true);

                // You need to set it to true if you want to send (output) a request body,
                //for example with POST or PUT requests. 
                //Sending the request body itself is done via the connection's output stream
                conn.setDoOutput(true);

                OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
                writer.write(result.toString());
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                os.close();

                int statusCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                /* 200 represents HTTP OK */
                if (statusCode ==  200) {

                    status = 1; // Successful

                }else{
                    status = 0; //"Failed to fetch data!";
                }

                conn.connect();
                is = conn.getInputStream();

            }else if(Objects.equals(method, "GET")){
                // request method is GET
                if (result.length() != 0) {
                    url += "?" + result.toString();
                }

                // request method is GET
                // defaultHttpClient
                URL urlr = new URL(url);
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlr.openConnection();

                conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
                /* for Get request */
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

                // You need to set it to true if you want to send (output) a request body,
                //for example with POST or PUT requests. 
                //Sending the request body itself is done via the connection's output stream
                conn.setDoOutput(true);

                conn.connect();
                is = conn.getInputStream();

            }           


        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line).append("\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

create_user.php

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
/*
 * Following code will create a new product row
 * All product details are read from HTTP POST Request
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// check for required fields
if (isset($_REQUEST['firstname']) && isset($_REQUEST['lastname']) && isset($_REQUEST['username']) && isset($_REQUEST['gusername']) && isset($_REQUEST['email']) && isset($_REQUEST['mobile']) && isset($_REQUEST['password']) && isset($_REQUEST['other']) && isset($_REQUEST['promocode'])) {

    $firstname= $_REQUEST['firstname'];
    $lastname= $_REQUEST['lastname'];
    $username= $_REQUEST['username'];
    $gusername= $_REQUEST['gusername'];
    $email= $_REQUEST['email'];
    $mobile= $_REQUEST['mobile'];
    $password= $_REQUEST['password'];
    $other= $_REQUEST['other'];
    $promocode= $_REQUEST['promocode'];

    // include db connect class
    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

    // connecting to db
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();
    $conn = $db->connect();

    // POST all iid from users table
    $results = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM user WHERE mobile='$mobile' or email='$email' or username='$username'") or die(mysql_error());

    // check for empty result
    if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 0) {

        date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Calcutta");
        $cur = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        // mysql inserting a new row
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO user (`userid`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `username`, `gusername`, `gender`, `email`, `mobile`, `password`, `other`, `promocode`, `log_entdate`) VALUES (NULL, '$firstname', '$lastname', '$username', '$gusername', NULL, '$email', '$mobile', '$password', '$other', '$promocode', '$cur')");

        // check if row inserted or not
        if ($result) {
            // successfully inserted into database
            $response["success"] = 1;
            $response["message"] = "Product successfully created.";

            // echoing JSON response
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            // failed to insert row
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

            // echoing JSON response
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    } else {

        $rows = mysqli_fetch_array($results, MYSQLI_BOTH);
//      echo $rows['mobile'];
//      echo $mobile;
        if($rows['mobile']==$mobile){
            // successfully updated
                    $response["success"] = 2;
                    $response["message"] = "mobile is same.";

                    // echoing JSON response
                    echo json_encode($response);

        } else if($rows['email']==$email){
            // successfully updated
                    $response["success"] = 2;
                    $response["message"] = "email is same.";

                    // echoing JSON response
                    echo json_encode($response);

        } else if($rows['username']==$username){
            // successfully updated
                    $response["success"] = 2;
                    $response["message"] = "username is same.";

                    // echoing JSON response
                    echo json_encode($response);

        }
    }

} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Comment: As of Android API 23, the legacy Apache HTTP library is [deprecated](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-28#apache-p). I don't know why are you using that library now. Are you sure the request from the client (Android) to the server (PHP) is hitting? I'd recommend you to use modern HTTP libraries like Retrofit or Volley Android. Use these libraries with Gson, Moshi, or Jackson JSON parsers. It'll help you to parse JSON easily.

Comment: Yea you are right it isnt hitting the server, its an old project that i reopened and now i am looking forward to rebuild it. i have no expirence in volley so i will have to see some docs.

Comment: Sure. Rebuild it with modern networking libraries. Go with Retrofit. It's better than Volley Android IMO. Good luck!